# How to get only a part of a line for I/O

Tags: ruby

I am trying to read this in Ruby

```
4 0.9
51 0.35
6 0.7
5 0.74
52 0.33
```

Where I want to take the first number in each row and store it in an array and then take the second number (a float) and put it in another array.

However, if I did something like `n = inputFile.gets` then I would get the entire line. How would I be able to achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: "if I did something like n = inputFile.gets then I would get the entire line" And why would that be bad?

Comment: how would I split that line from gets?

Comment: With `split`????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no problem with getting the entire line, you can just split it. try this:

```
first_nums = []
second_nums = []
input_file = File.open('file.in').read
input_file.each_line do |line|
  num1, num2 = line.split(' ')
  first_nums << num1
  second_nums << num2
end

first_nums #=> [4, 51, 6, 5, 52]
second_nums #=> [0.9, 0.35, 0.7, 0.74, 0.33]
```

if you absolutely need to use `gets`, then you can try this

```
first_nums = []
second_nums = []
while (line = inputFile.gets) do
   num1, num2 = line.split(' ')
   first_nums << num1
   second_nums << num2
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to do a inputfile.gets and then get that entire line, and then split that into the 2 numbers and then assign it?

Comment: is there a reason you need to use the `gets` method vs `each_line`?

Comment: You show the elements of `first_nums` to be integers and the elements of `second_numbers` to be floats, but nowhere do you convert the strings read from the file to numbers.

Comment: "is there a reason you need to use the gets" - if one reads from stdin, which is often the case in problems with this shape of input :)

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'pp'

data = Hash.new{|hash,key| hash[key] = []} #Instead of returning nil for a non existent key,
                                           #execute hash[new_key] = [] and return the array

File.open('data.txt') do |f|
  while line = f.gets
    col1, col2 = line.split
    data['col1'] << col1
    data['col2'] << col2
  end
end

pp data
p data['col1']

--output:--
{"col1"=>["4", "51", "6", "5", "52"],
 "col2"=>["0.9", "0.35", "0.7", "0.74", "0.33"]}

["4", "51", "6", "5", "52"]
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a file with test data.

```
data =<<END
4 0.9
51 0.35
6 0.7
5 0.74
52 0.33
END

FName = 'test'
File.write(FName, data)
  #=> 35
```

Now read the file and compute the desired return value.

```
ai, af = File.readlines(FName).map(&:split).transpose
  #=> [["4", "51", "6", "5", "52"], ["0.9", "0.35", "0.7", "0.74", "0.33"]]
[ai.map(&:to_i), af.map(&:to_f)]
  #=> [[4, 51, 6, 5, 52], [0.9, 0.35, 0.7, 0.74, 0.33]]
```

Comment: Why the extra spaces? They do nothing.

Comment: @Sergio, I just wanted to point out that `str.split`, which is the same as str.split(/\s+/)` removes any extra spaces, but I suppose that's not necessary.